# Javascript Phaser3 Assets Not Loading In Create Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, phaser-framework

I'm trying to do what seems to be basic image loading into my phaser3 game outside Phaser's preload function, but nothing is working.

I tried:

- Lazy loading function in my utils.js:

```
dynImgLoader(textureKey,x,y,asset)
{
    let loader = new Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin(this.scene);
    loader.image(textureKey,asset);
    loader.once(Phaser.Loader.Events.COMPLETE, ()=>
    {
        console.log('sprite ready for usage');
    })
    loader.start();
}
```

When called it still gives me the default phaser asset image (not loaded)

- I tried what this [tutorial](https://newbedev.com/phaser-loading-images-dynamically-after-preload) told me in index.js in create function:

```
    this.load.image('arc_red', arc_red);
    this.load.onLoadComplete.add(this);
    this.load.start();
```

Still does not work.

Question:

How do I "dynamically" load assets for a multiplayer web socket game without using the preload function? And why is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code in the `create` function *(or other non `preload` functions)* it should work:.

```
this.load.image(key, url);   // add task
this.load.once('complete', callback, scope);  // add callback of 'complete' event
this.load.start();                     // start loading
```

I got it from [this documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/loader/#loading-after-preload-stage), and it works in my demo code.

Here a working [example on Phaser.io](http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/loader/image/load-image-on-click)

Comment: hello thank you for the response. I put ```this.load.image('arc_red', arc_red);   
    this.load.once('complete', ()=>{console.log('image loaded!')}, this);  
    this.load.start();``` in my create function and it still appears to not load when I later assign a sprite to that texture key. I'm probably doing something morbidly wrong.

Comment: my texture turned red when I used the function I made to create sprite in the callback. But I can't access the sprite anywhere since it doesn't get stored into my state object

Comment: @IAmNoob are you loading the images from a different domain? or are all image Urls relative? Is there an error in the browser console?

Comment: I'm using webpack, and a localhost test server. My assets folder is located in the same directory as the js file, the path should be correct. arc_red variable is the file I imported from './assets/arc_red.png' . It gives me no errors and it logs the string in call back when I use the variable I stored the imported file in. However, when I set the path as a string I get an error ```XHRLoader.js?0bd9:57 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/arc_red.png 404 (Not Found)```.

Comment: @IAmNoob if everything is on the same Server, the example on phaser.io in my answer should work. The problem with webpack is, as you know, that depending on the config, the image could inlined,in another output folder, or... . you could put the absolute paht of the image into the load script, just to see how you can locate it on the webserver.

Comment: I don't know my way around webpack, I'm actually a newbie to it. What is the load script? and where can I locate it?

Comment: @IAmNoob sorry I wanted to say, you can get the absolut path of the image of you webserver `http://localhost....` and put the url in the image load script of phaser `this.load.image(...)`, to see if it works. like this you can see if it is a webpack/webserver issue or a phaser code problem.

Comment: so it gives me 404 for http://localhost:8080/assets/arc_red.png and I tried also http://localhost:8080/arc_red.png. I tried in my testing earlier to search if the resource is even on the server but it seems like it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way i really appreciate it.

Comment: do you think it's because to "dynamically load" another image means to rebundle the entire output file to include the image? If so, is there a better server thing I can use?

Comment: @IAmNoob no problem. :) yes, i could be because of webpack,(depending on the config and used plugins, images a inline/bundeld/copied, or so). I can't really say what the problem is, but if there is a output directory you could manually copy the `asset` folder into the output folder. just to see if phaser works, and than solve the rebundling with webpack.(check the `webpack.config.js` the `output` properties)